# Create custom search page with solr and facet-api

Tags: search

I am building a custom search page, and so I have installed :

Apache Solr Access (apachesolr_access)
Apache Solr framework (apachesolr)
Apache Solr search (apachesolr_search)
Current Search Blocks (current_search)
Facet API (facetapi)

All works fine but my search page is simply formatted like this :
1.results 
2.current search
3.sort
4.filters

My question is how easily theme my search page as I want ?

In my theme I want to override search-results.tpl.php but how call the current search and sorts and after filters like I want to put them ??
Is this a good solution ?

Thanks to answer ;)

Ju